# Error when using Mongoose ArrayFilters to update nested subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Mongoose collection of which I want to update a nested subdocument.

The basic setup is this:

- a parent entry (Map)
- which contains an array of children (Phases)
- each child consists of one or more grandchildren (Steps).

---

I want to be able to find a grandchild and update it. My approach is to find the parent (Map) that contains the grandchild and then update it.

These are my simplified schemas:

```
const phaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    color: String,
    steps: [
      new mongoose.Schema(
        {
          name: String,
          body: String,
          entry: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
            ref: 'entry',
            default: null
          }
        },
        { timestamps: false }
      )
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: false, _id: true }
)

const mapSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    phases: [phaseSchema]
  },
  { timestamps: false }
)

export const Map = mongoose.model('map', mapSchema)
```

**I'm trying to use ArrayFilters to find and update the subdocument, but to no luck:**

```
req.body = {
    map_id: 'some_mongoose_id',
    step_id: 'some_other_mongoose_id'
}
const newEntryId = 'a_new_mongoose_id'

// Find the parent (Map) and update it
const UpdatedMap = await Map.update(
    { _id: req.body.map_id }, 
    {
        $set: {
          'phases.$[i].steps.$[j].entry': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(newEntryId)
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                'i.steps._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.step_id)
            },
            {
                'j._id:': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.step_id)
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

This throws the following error:

> **Error: Could not find path "phases.0.steps.0._id:" in schema**

Coincidentally, the phase and step I'm trying to update are both at index 0.

If I swap out the arrayFilters and hardcode the indexes, like so `$set: {'phases.0.steps.0.entry': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(newEntryId)'}`, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `i` is what's causing the error and it's also redundant. the nested arrayFilter will work as required without it.

```
const UpdatedMap = await Map.update(
    { _id: req.body.map_id }, 
    {
        $set: {
          'phases.steps.$[j].entry': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(newEntryId)
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                'j._id:': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.step_id)
            }
        ]
    }
)
```